# have a question in the book "introduction to modern cryptography"

Tags: encryption, decryption-oracle

"introduction to modern cryptography. 2ed" in page 254

"By obtaining sufficiently many estimates and letting $x_{i}$ be the majority value, $A{'}$can ensure that $x_{i}$ is equal to $gl(x, e^{i})$ with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{2n}$.

Why is the probability $1-\frac{1}{2n}$?

Comment: Who is the author ? Also give us more context , not sure how many has that book to read it and tell u

Comment: Introduction to Modern Cryptography (2nd edition) author: Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell. Well, I found the proof in "Foundation of Cryptography, volume I", but I still don't understand.

Comment: type the problem and proof to get more help

Comment: Yehuda Lindell is around here, so maybe you get an answer from the author himself...

Comment: Could somebody please edit the title into something useful? Currently it is not even clear for what cryptographic algorithm or protocol the probability is calculated!

Answer (score 4):

By taking enough samples, it is possible to ensure that the majority value is the correct one with high probability. To prove this, you use Chernoff's bound. Now, the more samples that you take, the higher the probability that the majority value is the correct one (when plugging into Chernoff). So, this is a parameter that you can choose however you want. We choose $1-\frac{1}{2n}$ since this is what we need to finish the proof. There is nothing special at all about it; and you can also get much higher probability by sampling more (but it's not needed). I hope that this is clear now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the replay. By the way, do you think there is a mistake on page 255 in the last 12th line. "We do this by having $A'$ run $A(x, r \oplus e^{i})$, and having $A'$ simply......", I think this should be $A(f(x), r \oplus e^{i})$.